# How to modify the IP packet destination IP address in Android?

Tags: networking, iptables

Here, I can type this in **Termux**

```
su
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 1.2.3.4 -j REJECT
iptables-save
```

to reject the packet so as to forbid the Application to visit a certain host. It works well.

However, now I want to make the Application **thinks it is visiting 1.2.3.4 but it is visiting 5.6.7.8 instead.** which means **change the IP packet's destination IP address from 1.2.3.4 to 5.6.7.8**

I tried many tutorials but ended up in a failure. Not working at all, the Application still visits 1.2.3.4.

Can anyone help me with this? By using ***iptables*** or any other method. My Android device is rooted with Magisk installed.

Comment: If the application uses host/dns names, you could edit your hosts file or use a local dns server to resolve those to different IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a destination NAT (DNAT), see [here](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html)

Specifically, in your example you would do one of:

`iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -d 1.2.3.4 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.6.7.8`

Of course, you would want the return packets to make the inverse translation, so it looks like the reply is coming from 1.2.3.4 again, so you need also on of these:

`iptables -t nat -I INPUT -s 5.6.7.8 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4`

(In the original answer I had PREROUTING/POSTROUTING instead of OUTPUT/INPUT, but that is when you are doing that in a router. For locally generated packets, OUTPUT/INPUT should be the correct one).